# regular expression in XPATH

Tags: delphi, xpath

How can I use the match function of the XPATH to search for whole words in an XML tag?

The follow code return "unknown method **matches** " :

```
XML_Doc:=CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0') as IXMLDOMDocument3;
XML_DOC.selectNodes('/DATI/DATO[matches(TEST_TAG,"\bTest\b")]');
```

Example XML FILE

```
<DATI>
 <DATO>
   <TEST_TAG>Test</TEST_TAG>
 </DATO>
 <DATO>
   <TEST_TAG>Test21</TEST_TAG>
 </DATO>
 <DATO>
   <TEST_TAG>Abc</TEST_TAG>
 </DATO>
</DATI>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matches` is XPath 2 and Msxml only supports XPath 1.
As far as I know there is no library supporting XPath 2 for Delphi. (although I wrote a XPath 2 library for Freepascal, it should be not so difficult to port)

You could use

```
/DATI/DATO[not(contains(TEST_TAG," "))]
```

to find words that do not contain a space, which is XPath 1.

Comment: Where is your XPath 2 library?

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers : on my [homepage](http://www.benibela.de/sources_en.html#internettools). Not much announced...

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose that by "word" you mean**:

> *Starting with a Latin alphabet letter and all characters contained are either latin letters or decimal digits*,

one can use an XPath expression to find exactly these:

```
  //TEST_TAG
    [contains('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
              substring(.,1,1)
              )
   and
     not(
     translate(.,
               'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
               '')
         )
    ]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//TEST_TAG
        [contains('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                  substring(.,1,1)
                  )
       and
         not(
         translate(.,
                   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
                   '')
             )
        ]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided one, but with an illegal "word" added):

```
<DATI>
    <DATO>
        <TEST_TAG>Test</TEST_TAG>
    </DATO>
    <DATO>
        <TEST_TAG>#$%Test21</TEST_TAG>
    </DATO>
    <DATO>
        <TEST_TAG>Abc</TEST_TAG>
    </DATO>
</DATI>
```

**evaluates the above XPath expression and copies the selected elements to the output:**

```
<TEST_TAG>Test</TEST_TAG>
<TEST_TAG>Abc</TEST_TAG>
```

**Do note**:

The currently-accepted answer incorrectly produces this:

```
<TEST_TAG>#$%Test21</TEST_TAG>
```

as an element whose string value is a "word".